# Custom NumberFormat not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change how my application displays currencies.

In the constructor of my Window I have the following code:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo { 
    CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",", 
    CurrencySymbol="§"};
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

The XAML is:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CurrencyValue, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=C}" />
```

But this does not change the default view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CurrencyValue, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='§ \{0:n2\}'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Wpf / silverlight bindings do not respect the thread current culture settings. You need to set the language manually.

Try setting the language of your root control in this way:

```
rootControl.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(cultureInfo.IetfLanguageTag);
```